# How to add colorAxis to non-plotted categoryAxis?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

[Updated fiddle, courtesy of echonax](http://jsfiddle.net/1hotquwf/8/).

I am trying to apply color coding to segments of a line plot in dimple.js, similar to [this example](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color). Specifically, I have some categorical data (the "status" field), where I want each status to correspond to a specific color.

I've tried all variations of `addColorAxis` that I can think of, but the solution eludes me.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 1000);
    chart = new dimple.chart(svg);
    chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);
    x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "project");
    y = chart.addTimeAxis("y", "date", "%Y-%m-%d", "%Y-%m-%d");

    y.addOrderRule("date");

    var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.plot.line, [x, y]);
    lines.data = [
            { "date" : '2016-01-01', "project" : "Grape", "status" : 1 },
            { "date" : '2016-01-08', "project" : "Grape", "status" : -2 },
            { "date" : '2016-01-07', "project" : "Apple", "status" : 3 },
            { "date" : '2016-01-08', "project" : "Apple", "status" : 1 },
            { "date" : '2016-01-02', "project" : "Banana", "status" : -2 },
            { "date" : '2016-01-15', "project" : "Banana", "status" : 2 },
        ];
    lines.lineWeight = 5;
    lines.lineMarkers = true;
```

---

Related: It seems like `y.addGroupOrderRule("date", false);` does have no effect at all for reversing the dates. I'd like the oldest dates at top, and newest dates at the bottom. Can't figure it out.

---

## Edit

My latest attempt was to replicate the [colorAxis example](http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color) for a single category, save for swapping the x and y axes.

```
var grape = [
        { "date" : '2016-01-01', "status" : 0, "fake_x" : 1},
        { "date" : '2016-01-08', "status" : 1, "fake_x" : 1}];
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);

var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, grape);
myChart.setBounds(60, 30, 500, 300);
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "fake_x");
var y = myChart.addTimeAxis("y", "date");

// Order the x axis by date
y.addOrderRule("date");

// Min price will be green, middle price yellow and max red
myChart.addColorAxis("status", ["green", "yellow", "red"]);

// Add a thick line with markers
var lines = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line); 
lines.lineWeight = 5;
lines.lineMarkers = true;

// Draw the chart
myChart.draw();
```

The result has the same problems though:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`var chart = new dimple.chart(svg);`

is the line that breaks your code
I've changed it to

`var chart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);`

and now it works. 
Here is an updated fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1hotquwf/8/

Comment: FYI you're using a very old version of dimple.  If you upgrade to the latest version your original code will work (I think).  I can't remember the first version to support series specific data but I think it was around version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work for a single axis, will post an update if/when I get it to work for the category axis as well.

```
var grape = [
        { "date" : '2016-01-01', "status" : 0, "fake_x" : 1},
        { "date" : '2016-01-15', "status" : 3, "fake_x" : 1},
        { "date" : '2016-01-08', "status" : 1, "fake_x" : 1}];

var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
// Create and Position a Chart
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, grape);
chart.setBounds(60, 30, 500, 300);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("y", "date")
chart.addMeasureAxis("x", "fake_x");

// Order the x axis by date
x.addOrderRule("date");

// Min price will be green, middle price yellow and max red
chart.addColorAxis("status", ["green", "yellow", "red"]);

// Add a thick line with markers
var lines = chart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line); 
lines.lineWeight = 5;
lines.lineMarkers = true;
```